# how to compute this expectation value

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

A random variable $X \sim N(0,1)$, compute $\Bbb E(X^n)$ .

I manage to do this by characteristic function. Now I try to compute this by moment generating function or do it directly. So I have 2 questions for 2 ways to compute that expectation.

1. Moment generating function, I have $$M_X(t)= e^{t^2/2},$$ but how to compute this $n$-th order derivative?
2. If I compute that directly, I have $$\Bbb E(X^n)=\int x^n {1 \over \sqrt {2 \pi}} e^{-x^2 \over 2}dx,$$ but how to work out this integral?

Comment: Go and read about gamma functions ...

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\left. \frac{d^n M(t)}{dx^n} \right|_{t=0} = M^{(n)}(0) = \mathbb{E}[X^n]
$$
If you try to work out a couple, a pattern will emerge... In particular, it's not hard to see that it is 0 for odd $n$, which you could also get from the symmetry of the original integral...

The integral is nasty, have to do by parts $n$ times, don't think normally we do it this way. The alternative is to use a clever substitution and convert it to a Gamma function.

**EDIT**
Note that
$$
\Gamma(t) = \int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}dx
$$
so you need to use the substitution $u = -x^2/2$ to get this to a $\Gamma$ form and then use identities on the $\Gamma$ funciton.

Comment: I have very limited experience for gamma function, could you give more detail how to do this trick?

Comment: is that derivative should be differentiated under t not x?

Comment: @DylanZhu not sure what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

Consider the expansion:
$\exp(t^2/2) = 1 + \frac{t^2}{2} + \frac{t^4}{8} + \frac{t^6}{48} + \cdots.$

In particular,
$$\exp(t^2/2) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(t^2/2)^k}{k!}.$$

So, now, for ${\rm E}[X^{2n}]$, take $2n$ times derivative of $\frac{t^{2n}}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot 8 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2n}$ [all other higher order terms will be $0$ on substituting $t=0$], which will simply be $(2n-1)(2n-3)\ldots 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 1$. This will give the $2n^{\rm th}$ moment of the standard normal. Note that the odd moments are all 0.

Comment: Thank you heropup for the edit! These symbols are so hard to put up  in here. I am trying to learn. :)